# How to use vim regex to make this substitution?

Tags: regex, vim

So I have multiple lines in my code with this pattern:

```
has_many :kites, dependent: :destroy
```

I want to use regex in vim to make a substitution such that the above becomes:

```
it { should have_many(:kites) }
```

This is the regex I'm using (note the 22s is the line number on which to make the substitution) but I'm getting a 'pattern not found'.

```
:22s/\s.*has_many (:[a-z]*),.*/it { should have_many(\1) }/g
```

Why is this not matching?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your parentheses are being taken literally. To make them a captured grouping, you need to escape them.

... Unless you want to use Vim’s “magic” mode(s). See `:h /magic`.

Comment: Thanks I just realized I was not escaping them with "\".

Answer (score 2):

Need to do something like this with backslashes to escape the parentheses:

```
:22s/\s.*has_many \(:[a-z]*\),.*/it { should have_many(\1) }/g
```